# unable to use VB Razor value as a class value in tr

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am having trouble using VB Razor template in the following scenario:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of TrialLearning.Message)
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>    
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.MessageTo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.MessageFrom)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.Message1)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@For Each item In Model
    @Code
        Dim readF As String = ""
        If item.MessageRead = False Then
            readF="info"
        End If
    End Code

    <tr class="@readF">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.MessageTo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.MessageFrom)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Message1)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.MessageID}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = item.MessageID}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.MessageID})
    </td>
</tr>
Next

</table>
```

I am using MVC 5 and Razor 3. Majority of this code is simple scaffolding code. I just need to change the class name for the `<tr>` depending upon the value of item.MessageRead value.

The class in tr says "> expected" , `</td>` says "identifier expected" and `<td>` says "Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement."

If someone could also point to the documentation for VB Razor syntax that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The below will work just fine. The problem with the above code was that I missed the "@" before the `<tr>`. Also I love how easy ternary operator makes things in terms of code.

```
@For Each item In Model
        @<tr class="@(IIf(item.MessageRead, "", "info"))">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.MessageTo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.MessageFrom)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Message1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.MessageID}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = item.MessageID}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.MessageID})
        </td>
    </tr>
    Next
```

Probably should pay more attention to my code before I post at forums asking for help. :-)